# Why is folder deletion not parallelized?

Tags: windows-10, cpu-usage, parallel-processing

When I Shift-delete a big folder, I see the following CPU usage:

[image]

Not all boxes are used. Is this inefficient?

This seems easily parallelizable to me, through divide-and-conquer. I tried manually selecting and deleting half of the stuff, then the other half, and that made more boxes full.

I hear recycling exhibits a different behaviour, though I have not tested that myself.

Comment: While we can make guesses, and probably even good guesses, they will only ever be guesses. Asking "why" questions on SuperUser usually results in their being closed because we aren't the people who actually wrote the software the questions are being asked about, and so do not know the reasons a particular method or process was chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Modern filesystems attempt to ensure data integrity is maintained at all times during writes. In the past I heard this referred to as "atomic" writes, in that it either completes successfully or not at all.

You can only send one command at a time to the actual disk, ignoring disk queues and caches, and a delete operation would be several reads (scan directory etc) and so on before the final writes that remove the item from the directory tree and mark the space as free.

Combined with modern use of journalling (which allows disk tasks to be rolled backwards or forwards depending on when they were interrupted) it could well be that the bottleneck is in actually queueing up tasks (reads/seeks/writes) for the disk controller.

Moving something to the recycle bin is simply moving a folder, there is far less to do to "delete" something that way as you are simply ammending a folder structure rather than marking a lot of data as no longer needed. Though when you empty your recycle bin you will end up back at the task of freeing up disk space again.

Answer (score 0):

This operation isn't bottlenecked by the CPU, but by the disk. You can't make the CPU go faster than the disk can store changes. Therefore CPU waits for the disk to do its job before submitting more work.

This effect is particularly amplified for operations on many small files, where the filesystem overhead is larger than the size of files themselves, so they appear to take unusually long to process.